# How can I link a GET to a GET?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
   <?php echo "<a href='".get_permalink()."'>get_the_title()"' /></a>";}?>
```

I am trying to link get_the_title() to the .get_permalink() GET. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know; what's the symptom?  What is `get_permalink`?

Comment: Functions aren't called in string context. Add a concatenation. Also add it to the href= part, and don't close the tag prematurely.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Badly written wordpress API without namespace prefixes. (Yes, that happens.)

Comment: Your question is not clear. Probably giving an additional, different description helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your 2 functions return something valid:

```
<?php
    $plink = get_permalink();
    $title = get_the_title();
    echo "<a href='{$plink}'>{$title}</a>";
 ?>
```

I think this is what you wanted, and saving variables is better for reading than to save them anonymously. You also have a "}" at the end of your statement. Maybe share the php runtime error or is this a logic error ?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo '<a href="'.get_perma_link().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
```

Use single quotes when you're outputting HTML!

Comment: Mostly the colors in your IDE tell you what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I wouldn't say it so harsh (**highly unrecommended**), because you might as well use single quotes for HTML quoting. (P.S. I do prefer single quoted HTML strings though, still it's *somewhat* personal preference)

Comment: Use echo when you use echo - concatenating the string first is not necessary.

Comment: You maybe should explain why using single-quotes in HTML is not recommended. Sounds a bit like a myth out of the swamps of the interwebs.

Comment: Seems I've lived a lie my entire life ;__;

Comment: Thanks for the help. For some reason the following is not outputting anything, and is preventing the rest of the code afterwards to display appropriately on the page:

`<?php echo '<a href="', get_perma_link(), '">', get_the_title(), '</a>';?>`

Comment: It's more recommended to use 1 for PHP and 1 for HTML to avoid escaping.